# Add My Order link active in customer account

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9.1

Right now in default magento when customer login into his/her account then Active menu shown to customer is **Account Dashboard**

I want to show **My orders** when customer login into account.
I used this peace of code.

```
<customer_account>
<reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="setActive"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path></action>
        </reference>
</customer_account>
```

but it didn't work. Please suggest me any solution or give me an alternate idea to do that.

Answer (score 1):

you can try below code in controller.

```
$this->loadLayout();

// add layout handle so that we will have the customer navigation on the right hand side

    $layout = $this->getLayout();
    $update = $layout->getUpdate();
    $this->addActionLayoutHandles();
    $update->addHandle('customer_account'); // add the customer navigation bar on the side
    $this->loadLayoutUpdates();
    $this->generateLayoutXml();
    $this->generateLayoutBlocks();
    $navigationBlock = $layout->getBlock('customer_account_navigation');
    // make sure we have an instantiation    
    if ($navigationBlock) {
        $navigationBlock->setActive('path/to/highlight'); // example: 'customer/address'
    }
    $this->_isLayoutLoaded = true;

    // render the layout
    $this->renderLayout();
```

So, please try this and let me know in case of any query.

Thanks

Comment: which controller? i am not using and third party of custom module.so should i make changes in core controller by ovewriting it, if yes then tell me the controller name

Answer (score 0):

Open `app\code\core\Mage\Customer\controllers\AccountController.php`

Find code  `$this->_loginPostRedirect()` in public function `loginPostAction()` and 
replace with `$this->_redirect('sales/order/history/');`